# How do I restart the debuggee without erasing all my breakpoints?

Tags: windbg

Each time I do a `.restart` (because I accidentally pressed F10 one too many times), WinDBG erases all my breakpoints. Is it possible to have it leave the breakpoints in place when restarting the debuggee?

Comment: save the workspace? does it store the breakpoints?

Comment: It saves `bu` breakpoints but not `bp` breakpoints, so the solution is use `bu` and save the workspace.

Comment: I don't even know what the workspace is :)

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540116(v=vs.85).aspx and this classic post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/05/07/uncovering-how-workspaces-work-in-windbg.aspx

Comment: Second link is broken, can use this archived version instead: https://web.archive.org/web/20190112003614/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2010/05/07/uncovering-how-workspaces-work-in-windbg/

Answer (score 7):

If you set breakpoints using `bu` rather than with `bp` breakpoints they are saved in the workspace. So do that, save the workspace, and that should to the trick.

Comment: I'm making breakpoints by clicking a source code line. Does that use bu or bp?

Comment: Those are unresolved breakpoints (`bu`). See here (last paragraph): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560012(v=vs.85).aspx You can verify this using `.bpcmds` which displays the commands used to set the current breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

this requires awk in path which i normally have in my setup

will work if it is windbg cdb or kd dont have to remember saying yes no always to questions

```
0:000> .shell -ci "bl" awk "{print \"bp \" $7}" >> c:\breaks.txt
.shell: Process exited

0:000> .restart
CommandLine: C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

774e04f6 cc              int     3
0:000> bl

0:000> $$>a< c:\breaks.txt

0:000> bl
 0 e 00fb1635     0001 (0001)  0:**** calc!WinMain
 1 e 75eaea11     0001 (0001)  0:**** USER32!MessageBoxA
 2 e 774855c8     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!NtCreateFile
```

also if there is no aslr 
saving the command history can help you restart the session in its full glory

```
.write_cmd_hist c:\foo.txt
```

edit

i just checked the clickety history is not part of the command history    neither `f9 key` press nor `clicking the hand icon` in windbg provides a history event

```
0:000> bl
 0 e 00a11022     0001 (0001)  0:**** helloworld!main+0x22
 1 e 00a11016     0001 (0001)  0:**** helloworld!main+0x16
0:000> .bpcmds
bu0 @@masm(`helloworld!c:\test\helloworld\helloworld.cpp:6+`);
bu1 @@masm(`helloworld!c:\test\helloworld\helloworld.cpp:5+`);
windbg> .write_cmd_hist c:\foo.txt
Wrote command history to 'c:\foo.txt'
0:000> .shell - type c:\foo.txt
Unknown option ' '
.write_cmd_hist c:\foo.txt
.bpcmds
bl
.cls
t <----- neither f8 ,f10 nor f5 gets recorded in the history
.echo foo
g helloworld!main
.shell: Process exited
Press ENTER to continue
<.shell waiting 1 second(s) for process>
<.shell process may need input>
```

Comment: Does `.write_cmd_hist` do anything for breakpoints set by clicking source lines? I'm not typing any commands in to set such breakpoints, I'm just clicking the appropriate source code line.

Comment: doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: And what about remote debugging? `.shell` runs on the target machine. Do we need to have `awk` on all the machines we debug? There is a builtin solution in WinDbg. Trying to reinvent the wheel just for the sake of reinventing it seems... uncalled for.